# How to trim ' . ' and ' | ' in a single command using PERL?

Tags: perl, trim

I have a string like this `$data = .|abc|bcd|cde|`.

I need the string like this : `abc|bcd|cde`.

So I do :

`$data =~ s/\|$//;       # trim the last '|' out...
$data =~ s/^\.| +//gm ;  #trim '.' in the begining
$data =~ s/^\|//;         # trim '|' in the begining`

But the problem I am facing is, the script is taking too long to execute. Is there any way to complete the whole operation with a single command ??

(Also tried `chop($data)` but that takes out only the last `|`)

Please suggest...

Comment: Does `$data` *always* start with `.|` and end in `|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data =~ s/(^[.|]*)|([.|]*$)//g;
```

That said, I don't assume that this will speed up your script significantly.

Comment: Tried this one but the result is like this : `|abc|bcd|cde` ... The '.' and the last '|' is gone but the '|' after the '.' remains. @Rene

Comment: I have edited my answer and you might have tried with my old version (where I have forgotten the first `*`).

Comment: but you were right, this isnt much on the speed. But when I dont trim my string, the script is very fast but the '.|' in the beginging gives me all the unwanted data as well (I'm using this string for a egrep command).

Comment: @user3446683: Do you call `egrep` from Perl? That doesn't seem to be a fast solution.

Comment: @choroba Yes, that command runs for ages (there are too many data as well), actually I am not much familiar with PERL at all but just working on a pre-existing code.

Comment: What are the other ways of doing this: what i am doing is, I get this string and I have another file which contains these strings ('abc' or 'bcd') , so i fetch them back using a perl script. Its too slow for large data... @choroba

Comment: @user3446683: Calling external commands is slow. Implementing everything in one language tends to be faster.

Comment: @choroba Guess have to figure something else. Anyways, thanks for your views. :)

Comment: If your script is slow it's probably not because of this substitution!

Answer (score 2):

Another way: `$data =~ s/^\.\|(.*)\|/$1/`

But as Rene said, your speed bottleneck is probably somewhere else in your script.